# Regex : Match digits with hyphens and white spaces only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match digits with at least 5 characters (for the whole string) connected by a hyphen or space (like a bank account number).

e.g

***"12345-62436-223434"***

***"12345 6789 123232"***

I should also be able to match

**"123-4567-890"**

The current pattern I'm using is 
`(\d[\s-]*){5,}[\W]`

But i'm getting these problems.

1. When I do this, I match all the white spaces after matching digits with at least 5 digit-characters
2. I'm going to replace this so I only want to match digits, not the white-spaces and hypens.

   When I get the match what I want to do is to mask it like the one below.

from "**12345-67890-11121**" to **"*****-*****-*****"**

or

from "**12345 67890 11121**" to **"***** ***** *****"**

My only problem is that I don't get to match it like what I want to.

Thanks!

Comment: whar regex flavor is this ??? javascript/python/ c#????

Comment: @AbdulHameed I really don't get the flavor, but I'll be doing this on java.

Comment: Two questions: 1) how many groupings of digits are there, and 2) how many digits are in each grouping?  Is there a range?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll update the question, I think the grouping is not necessary, I should also match something like this.

"123 4567 89" or "123-4567-89"

Comment: is 123-4 a positive test case according to your new edit??

Comment: nope, 123-4 is not possible but 123-45 is possible.

Comment: will the input always contain hyphens or spaces or are they optional? what is the range of groupings??  min groupings max groupings

Comment: @AbdulHameed the hypens or spaces are optional, I don't have a specific number of groupings, it can be one or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one might work for you (probably some false-positives, though):

```
\d[ \d-]{3,}\d
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VEaHY1/4).

Comment: this will not match `-` as requested in question

Comment: this one is good, I just had to make some modifications \d[ \d-]{5,}\d 
nonetheless, thank you so much man!

Comment: Note: This regex fails the requirement of having 5 or more digits, see here: https://www.regex101.com/r/06C93P/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You're right, a false positive as stated.

Comment: this will not satisfy your requirement of minimum 5 digits.. `1- -5` will be matched

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think this one is right, because I need at least 5 digits for the whole string, not just within the group.

Comment: @Aaron Please learn how to ask a question, your requirements changed substantially at least 2-3 times in the course of so many answers.

Comment: @Jan I have some additional question, is it possible to not match the last four characters? e.g 
Original String :  1234-5678-903-4
Matched String : 1234-5678-

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry about that, I just realized it after seeing this answer, anyway thank you so much for suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
(\d{5,})(?:-|\s)(\d{5,})(?:-|\s)(\d{5,})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiT1E6/1)

**EDIT:**

```
(\d+)(?:-|\s)(\d+)(?:-|\s)(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiT1E6/2)

Comment: I will update the question, but this is very helpful thanks!

Comment: I also need to match something like this "123-4567-890", what I mean is that there should be at least 5 digits inside the whole string weather they are consecutive or not

Comment: Oh! I am afraid that is not possible directly using regex. What you can do instead is just loop over the captured groups and count the number of digits present.

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to take your existing pattern, and then add a positive lookahead which asserts that there are *seven* or more characters in the pattern.  Assuming that there are two spaces or dashes in the account number, this will guarantee that there are five or more digits.

You can try using the following regex:

```
^(?=.{7,}$)((\\d+ \\d+ \\d+)|(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+))$
```

**Test code:**

```
String input = "123-4567-890";
boolean match = input.matches("^(?=.{7,}$)((\\d+ \\d+ \\d+)|(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+))$");
if (match) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

If you need to first fish out the account numbers from a larger document/source, then do so and afterwards you can apply the regex logic above.